# Struts 1 - Setar valores disponíveis no bean:message

Tags: internacionalização

Trabalho com *java web* e, até 1 mês atrás não usávamos nenhum Framework na empresa.

Agora estou usando *Struts* 1 e surgiu uma dúvida que não estou encontrando resposta em lugar nenhum. Sem mais enrolação vou explicar o problema:

O sistema precisa ser traduzido em 3 idiomas, já resolvi isto utilizando oa arquivos `.property`, porem preciso que os valores venham do banco e não de um arquivo, já tenho o banco e vou jogar os valores em uma *HasMap* assim como o Struts faz com os arquivos, o que preciso saber é como eu faço para esse *HasMap* ficar no lugar no arquivo, algo como setar o `org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE`.

Comment: Não há a possibilidade de utilizar uma classe estática?